# Bug animação menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

Gostaria de que a transição do efeito do menu tivesse o mesmo tempo quando abre e quando fecha.

```js
 
 if( 'ontouchstart' in window ){ var click = 'touchstart'; }
 else { var click = 'click'; }


 $('div.burger').on(click, function(){

   if( !$(this).hasClass('open') ){ openMenu(); } 
   else { closeMenu(); }

 });
 

 $('div.menu ul li a').on(click, function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  closeMenu();
 });  


 function openMenu(){
  
  $('div.circle').addClass('expand');
     
  $('div.burger').addClass('open'); 
  $('div.x, div.y, div.z').addClass('collapse');
  $('.menu li').addClass('animate');
  
  setTimeout(function(){ 
   $('div.y').hide(); 
   $('div.x').addClass('rotate30'); 
   $('div.z').addClass('rotate150'); 
  }, 70);
  setTimeout(function(){
   $('div.x').addClass('rotate45'); 
   $('div.z').addClass('rotate135');  
  }, 120);
  
  

 }
 
 function closeMenu(){

  $('div.burger').removeClass('open'); 
  $('div.x').removeClass('rotate45').addClass('rotate30'); 
  $('div.z').removeClass('rotate135').addClass('rotate150');    
  $('div.circle').removeClass('expand');
  $('.menu li').removeClass('animate');
  
  setTimeout(function(){    
   $('div.x').removeClass('rotate30'); 
   $('div.z').removeClass('rotate150');    
  }, 50);
  setTimeout(function(){
   $('div.y').show(); 
   $('div.x, div.y, div.z').removeClass('collapse');
  }, 70);             
  
 }
```

```css
* { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
body {
 background: #383c55;
 width: 100%; 
 height: 100%;
 font:12px "Open Sans", sans-serif; 
}
#view-code{
  color:#4183d7; 
  font-size:13px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:700;
  text-decoration:none;
  position:absolute;top:640px; left:50%;margin-left:-35px;
}
div.screen{
 width:320px;
 height:560px; 
 overflow:hidden;
 position:absolute; 
 top:50px; 
 left:50%;
  margin-left:-160px;
 background:#31558a;
}

.list{margin-top:36px; text-align:left;}
.item{
 height:115px;
 margin-top:30px 0;
 padding-left:115px;
 clear:both;
}
.item .img, .item span{background:#214273; border-radius:3px;}
.item .img{float:left; width:71px; height:71px; margin-left:-93px;}
.item span{height:11px; width:180px; margin-bottom:19px; float:left;}
.item span:nth-of-type(3){width:75px; margin-botom:0;}

div.burger {
 height: 30px; 
 width: 40px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 11px; 
 left: 21px;
 cursor: pointer; 
}
 div.x,
 div.y,
 div.z {
  position: absolute; margin: auto;
  top: 0px; bottom: 0px;  
  background: #fff;
  border-radius:2px;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
       -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
          transition: all 200ms ease-out;
 }  
 div.x, div.y, div.z { height: 3px; width: 26px; }
 div.y{top: 18px;}
 div.z{top: 37px;}
 div.collapse{
  top: 20px;
  background:#4a89dc;
  -webkit-transition: all 70ms ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 70ms ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all 70ms ease-out;
       -o-transition: all 70ms ease-out;
          transition: all 70ms ease-out;
 }
  
 
 div.rotate30{
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg); 
     -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); 
     transform: rotate(30deg); 
  -webkit-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
       -o-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
          transition: all 50ms ease-out;     
 }
 div.rotate150{
  -ms-transform: rotate(150deg); 
     -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg); 
     transform: rotate(150deg); 
  -webkit-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
       -o-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
          transition: all 50ms ease-out;     
 }
 
 div.rotate45{
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); 
     -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
     transform: rotate(45deg); 
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
       -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
          transition: all 100ms ease-out;     
 }
 div.rotate135{
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg); 
     -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg); 
     transform: rotate(135deg); 
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
       -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
          transition: all 100ms ease-out;     
 }

div.navbar{height:73px;background:#385e97;}

div.circle{ 
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 0px;
 height: 0px; 
 position:absolute;
 top: 35px;
 left: 36px;
 background:#fff;
 opacity:1;
 -webkit-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
    -moz-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
     -ms-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
      -o-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
         transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000); 
}
div.circle.expand{
 width:1200px;
 height:1200px;
 top: -560px;
 left: -565px;  
 -webkit-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
    -moz-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
     -ms-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
      -o-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
         transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);     
 
}
div.menu {
 height: 568px; 
 width: 320px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px; left: 0px;
}
div.menu ul li {
 list-style: none;
 position:absolute;
 top:50px;;
 left:0;
 opacity:0;
 width:320px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:0px;
 -webkit-transition: all 70ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
    -moz-transition: all 70ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
     -ms-transition: all 70ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
      -o-transition: all 70ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
         transition: all 70ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
}
div.menu ul li a {
 color:#4a89dc;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 text-decoration:none; 
 letter-spacing:3px;   
}

div.menu li.animate{
 font-size:21px;
 opacity:1;
 -webkit-transition: all 150ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
    -moz-transition: all 150ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
     -ms-transition: all 150ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
      -o-transition: all 150ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
         transition: all 150ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
}
div.menu li.animate:nth-of-type(1){ 
 top:120px;
 transition-delay: 0.0s; 
}
div.menu li.animate:nth-of-type(2){
 top:190px;
 transition-delay: 0.03s; 
   
}
div.menu li.animate:nth-of-type(3){
 top:260px;
 transition-delay: 0.06s;  
 
}
div.menu li.animate:nth-of-type(4){
 top:330px;
 transition-delay: 0.09s;  
 
}
div.menu li.animate:nth-of-type(5){
 top:400px;
 transition-delay: 0.12s;  
 
}
div.menu li.animate:nth-of-type(6){
 top:470px;
 transition-delay: 0.15s; 
   
}
```

```html
     
 
    
        <div class="screen">
         <div class="navbar"></div>

        
         <div class="circle"></div>
   <div class="menu">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Share</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Activity</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Settings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>               
   <div class="burger">
    <div class="x"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
                <div class="z"></div>
   </div>    

  </div> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Cara ao meu ver está muito próximo um dou outro... mas se vc quer mudar vc tem que explica se vc quer os dois iguais como o estilo que abre ou os dois iguais com o estilo de quando fecha... ?

Comment: O tempo da transição de quando abre, está muito mais rápido de quando fecha, eu gostaria que ficasse os dois com o mesmo tempo, que seria o tempo que fecha.

Comment: tens noção de como solucionar esse bug hugo? Sei que tu é ferra no css

Comment: Cara deixei uma resposta ai com detalhes, da uma olhada, se tiver qq dúvida comenta lá. Eu tinha esquecido dessa pergunta rss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara esse `cubic-bezier` está meio estranho ele começa muito rápido e depois fica muito devagar, e na volta muito devagar e depois muito rápido, além disso a animação de inicio tem `400ms` e a volta `300ms`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu troquei o `cubic-bezier` por um e `ease-in-out` assim vc tem uma animação mais equilibrada. Repare como ele é mais "simétrico" que o modelo acima.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com isso eu consegui equilibrar a ida e a volta como o mesmo tempo de 300ms na ida e volta e mantendo a "simetria" de início e fim da animação na ida e na volta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
    
    * { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
body {
 background: #383c55;
 width: 100%; 
 height: 100%;
 font:12px "Open Sans", sans-serif; 
}
#view-code{
  color:#4183d7; 
  font-size:13px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:700;
  text-decoration:none;
  position:absolute;top:640px; left:50%;margin-left:-35px;
}
div.screen{
 width:320px;
 height:560px; 
 overflow:hidden;
 position:absolute; 
 top:50px; 
 left:50%;
  margin-left:-160px;
 background:#31558a;
}

.list{margin-top:36px; text-align:left;}
.item{
 height:115px;
 margin-top:30px 0;
 padding-left:115px;
 clear:both;
}
.item .img, .item span{background:#214273; border-radius:3px;}
.item .img{float:left; width:71px; height:71px; margin-left:-93px;}
.item span{height:11px; width:180px; margin-bottom:19px; float:left;}
.item span:nth-of-type(3){width:75px; margin-botom:0;}

div.burger {
 height: 30px; 
 width: 40px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 11px; 
 left: 21px;
 cursor: pointer; 
}
 div.x,
 div.y,
 div.z {
  position: absolute; margin: auto;
  top: 0px; bottom: 0px;  
  background: #fff;
  border-radius:2px;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
       -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
          transition: all 200ms ease-out;
 }  
 div.x, div.y, div.z { height: 3px; width: 26px; }
 div.y{top: 18px;}
 div.z{top: 37px;}
 div.collapse{
  top: 20px;
  background:#4a89dc;
  -webkit-transition: all 70ms ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 70ms ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all 70ms ease-out;
       -o-transition: all 70ms ease-out;
          transition: all 70ms ease-out;
 }
  
 
 div.rotate30{
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg); 
     -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); 
     transform: rotate(30deg); 
  -webkit-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
       -o-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
          transition: all 50ms ease-out;     
 }
 div.rotate150{
  -ms-transform: rotate(150deg); 
     -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg); 
     transform: rotate(150deg); 
  -webkit-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
       -o-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
          transition: all 50ms ease-out;     
 }
 
 div.rotate45{
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); 
     -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
     transform: rotate(45deg); 
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
       -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
          transition: all 100ms ease-out;     
 }
 div.rotate135{
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg); 
     -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg); 
     transform: rotate(135deg); 
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
       -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
          transition: all 100ms ease-out;     
 }

div.navbar{height:73px;background:#385e97;}

div.circle{ 
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 0px;
 height: 0px; 
 position:absolute;
 top: 35px;
 left: 36px;
 background:#fff;
 opacity:1;
 -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
         transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
div.circle.expand{
 width:1200px;
 height:1200px;
 top: -560px;
 left: -565px;  
 -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
         transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
div.menu {
 height: 568px; 
 width: 320px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px; left: 0px;
}
div.menu ul li {
 list-style: none;
 position:absolute;
 top:50px;;
 left:0;
 opacity:0;
 width:320px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:0px;
 -webkit-transition: all 70ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
    -moz-transition: all 70ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
     -ms-transition: all 70ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
      -o-transition: all 70ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
         transition: all 70ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
}
div.menu ul li a {
 color:#4a89dc;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 text-decoration:none; 
 letter-spacing:3px;   
}

div.menu li.animate{
 font-size:21px;
 opacity:1;
 -webkit-transition: all 150ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
    -moz-transition: all 150ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
     -ms-transition: all 150ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
      -o-transition: all 150ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
         transition: all 150ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
}
div.menu li.animate:nth-of-type(1){ 
 top:120px;
 transition-delay: 0.0s; 
}
div.menu li.animate:nth-of-type(2){
 top:190px;
 transition-delay: 0.03s; 
   
}
div.menu li.animate:nth-of-type(3){
 top:260px;
 transition-delay: 0.06s;  
 
}
div.menu li.animate:nth-of-type(4){
 top:330px;
 transition-delay: 0.09s;  
 
}
div.menu li.animate:nth-of-type(5){
 top:400px;
 transition-delay: 0.12s;  
 
}
div.menu li.animate:nth-of-type(6){
 top:470px;
 transition-delay: 0.15s; 
   
}
    
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
     
 
     
 
    
        <div class="screen">
         <div class="navbar"></div>

        
         <div class="circle"></div>
   <div class="menu">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Share</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Activity</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Settings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>               
   <div class="burger">
    <div class="x"></div>
    <div class="y"></div>
                <div class="z"></div>
   </div>    

  </div> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
if( 'ontouchstart' in window ){ var click = 'touchstart'; }
 else { var click = 'click'; }


 $('div.burger').on(click, function(){

   if( !$(this).hasClass('open') ){ openMenu(); } 
   else { closeMenu(); }

 });
 

 $('div.menu ul li a').on(click, function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  closeMenu();
 });  


 function openMenu(){
  
  $('div.circle').addClass('expand');
     
  $('div.burger').addClass('open'); 
  $('div.x, div.y, div.z').addClass('collapse');
  $('.menu li').addClass('animate');
  
  setTimeout(function(){ 
   $('div.y').hide(); 
   $('div.x').addClass('rotate30'); 
   $('div.z').addClass('rotate150'); 
  }, 70);
  setTimeout(function(){
   $('div.x').addClass('rotate45'); 
   $('div.z').addClass('rotate135');  
  }, 120);
  
  

 }
 
 function closeMenu(){

  $('div.burger').removeClass('open'); 
  $('div.x').removeClass('rotate45').addClass('rotate30'); 
  $('div.z').removeClass('rotate135').addClass('rotate150');    
  $('div.circle').removeClass('expand');
  $('.menu li').removeClass('animate');
  
  setTimeout(function(){    
   $('div.x').removeClass('rotate30'); 
   $('div.z').removeClass('rotate150');    
  }, 50);
  setTimeout(function(){
   $('div.y').show(); 
   $('div.x, div.y, div.z').removeClass('collapse');
  }, 70);             
  
 }

</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```